# Libgit2: Commit from Oid

Tags: rust, libgit2

I want to print history:

```rust
fn print_history() -> Result<(), git2::Error> {
    let repo = git2::Repository::open(".")?;
    let mut walk = repo.revwalk()?;
    walk.push_head()?;

    for oid_result in walk {
        let oid = oid_result?;
        println!("{}", oid.commit().summary());
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

But one does not simply get commit from oid:

```
println!("{}", oid.commit().summary());
                   ^^^^^^ method not found in `Oid`
```

The documentation for [Oid](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Oid.html) does not mention [Commit](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Commit.html) or vice versa. I could need a hint.

Answer (score 0):

It's on the toplevel Repository type: [find_commit](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Repository.html#method.find_commit)

So one more step is needed:

```
let commit = repo.find_commit(oid)?;
```